# Custom DataType for Umbraco containing MultiUrlPicker

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, umbraco6

I am trying to create a custom `DataType` for Umbraco containing group of elements which include a `TextBox`, `MediaPicker` and a `MultiUrlPicker`. I can create a Text Box using the following snippet:

```
var textBox = new TextBox();
```

and a Media Picker using the following snippet:

```
var mediaPicker = new SimpleMediaPicker();
```

The above two work fine but struggling with how to add MultiUrlPicker in my custom control. I am trying to use the `uComponnents` package of Umbraco and it provides `MultiUrlPickerDataType` and `MultiUrlPickerDataEditor` classes but I am struggling to how to initiate and insert these into my control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work finally using the following code:

```
var urlPicker = new MultiUrlPickerDataEditor {Settings = new MultiUrlPickerSettings{ Standalone = false }};
```

Posting it here, in case anyone else ever struggle with the same thing.